# Langchain(V 0.1.11) Performance lagging in mongodb chat history

Tags: python, mongodb, langchain

I noticed that the MongoDBChatMessageHistory(LLM chatbot) class object is attempting to create an index during connection, causing each request to take longer than usual. This issue persisted until Langchain version 0.1.11. During this time, requests were taking around 3 to 4 seconds to process.

Answer (score 0):

However, in Langchain version 0.1.11, this feature is not present. But in the upcoming version, we can expect this feature, with an optional provision for index_creation. Since index creation is a one-time operation, whoever is working with LangChain's MongoDBChatMessageHistory class should use the improved arguments from the upcoming version.

Proposed Example provided here

```
mongoconn=MongoDBChatMessageHistory(connection_string: str="connection string",
        session_id: str="session_id: ",
        database_name: str = "database name"
        collection_name: str = collection name
        index_creation:bool =True #set it to False once index created
)
```